# hyperledger fabric chaincode paging question

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I use Mango Query Server to query data, for example :{"selector":{"number":10},"limit":3,"skip":2}

but the parameter: 'limit' and 'skip' not work.The result of the query count is not 3. I want to implementation paging action.

```
var queryString = `{"selector":{"number":10},"limit":3,"skip":2}`
resultsIterator, err := stub.GetQueryResult(queryString)
if err != nil{
    log.Error(model.ERRNMCC0006)
    return nil, err, model.ERRNMCC0006
}
defer resultsIterator.Close()

var resArr []string

for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
    queryResponse, err := resultsIterator.Next()
    if err != nil{
        log.Error(model.ERRNMCC0007)
        return nil, err, model.ERRNMCC0007
    }

    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString(string(queryResponse.Value))

    resArr = append(resArr, buffer.String())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB implementation strips out the ‘limit’ and ‘skip’ values in the query, replacing the ‘limit’ with whatever is set in the peer’s queryLimit configuration. Skip is always reset to 0.
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5369

For pagination in (v1.3), you can use functions like
`GetStateByRangeWithPagination()` `GetStateByPartialCompositeKeyWithPagination()` `GetQueryResultWithPagination()`

You have to pass pageSize and bookmark from previous query result.
Note: this functions are not available below V1.3

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2809

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AzcVjVbuvZGRozfNe3ksIpK-cBMlhhbGOUZhg2bzPW8/edit

https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetQueryResultWithPagination